# In "Going Places" by A. R. Barton, does Sophie really meet Danny Casey?

Tags: short-stories, a-r-barton

In the short story "[Going Places](https://archive.org/details/ncert-lefl1/lefl108/mode/2up)" by A. R. Barton, the plot revolves around the story of a schoolgirl Sophie, who fantasizes over many things, but no one ever believes her.

Can someone please confirm whether she had ever met Danny Casey for real, or whether it was a mere figment of her imagination?

I've searched this online, and most of the answers (on other websites) don't bother to provide evidence against their claim that Sophie had never met Danny Casey.